# How do you move text to the left when scrolling?

Tags: css, shopify

I'am making a shopify store, and I wanted a similar effect to https://www.carbonbeauty.com/. I have never used css before but I want to know how they move the text to the left when you start to scroll.

Comment: Looking up some info on parallax scrolling effects will get you in the right direction, although it might take some more work if you've never used CSS. https://codepen.io/rachsmith/post/how-to-move-elements-on-scroll-in-a-way-that-doesn-t-suck-too-bad

Comment: StackOverflow is more for helping people with particular coding issues not for necessarily helping people Google a question. With that said these [one](https://css-tricks.com/slide-in-as-you-scroll-down-boxes/) and [two](https://codepen.io/simoncodrington/pen/Mwgqqd) links may help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this, where you target the element that has the text you want to move, and you can make wScroll either positive or negative to move it left or right:

```
enter code here



$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        //parallax for the main title

        $('element you want to move').css({
            'transform' : 'translateX('wScroll+'px)'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you also might need to change the speed of the item moving, and you can do that by dividying or multiplying wscroll by another number inside the translate declaration.